# Trouble with powershell commas

Tags: powershell, wmic

Im trying to write a very brief powershell script that runs a few commands, pipes their output to a text file, and then does a search against a keyword.

I cant figure out what to change however for this line:

```
wmic service get name, startname | out-File "$pwd\admin\wmic.txt"

WMIC.exe : Invalid GET Expression.
At \\test.ps1:7 char:5
+ wmic <<<<  service get name startname | out-File "$pwd\admin\wmic.txt"
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Invalid GET Expression.:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I believe the error is generated from the ',' as powershell uses the comma to create an array.
Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I'm currious why you are using WMIC? PS has much better ways to access WMI (Get-WMIObject). It even has cmlets that are specific to working with services (Get-Service).

Comment: Have you tried "name, startname"?

Comment: Quotes do not work, I believe its not syntactically correct.

Comment: I will give that a shot EBGreen.  Still semi-new to PS and was unaware of that cmdlet. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```powershell
wmic service get name"," startname| out-File "$pwd\admin\wmic.txt"
```

This is easy to resolve comma, no change at all.

Comment: I think this comment is better and should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

Beginning with PowerShell 3.0 there is the new escaping operator `--%` available (see *magic parameter* in the [release notes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/)):

```
wmic --% service get name, startname | out-File "$pwd\admin\wmic.txt"
```

This operator is known as the *stop-parsing* operator, and it instructs PowerShell to stop interpreting input from that point forward as PowerShell commands or expressions (see docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.1)).

Comment: Thanks for this @sevenforce. To be pedantic, an equivalent command is `wmic service get --% name, start name | out-File ...` because it's the commas and whitespace that start to cause the problem

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question lies in the use of the Start-Process cmdlet. This will make interpretation of command line arguments much easier, since you can also construct the command line arguments ahead of time, store them in a variable, and then reference them using the variable name.

```
$WmicArgs = 'service get name, startname';
Start-Process -FilePath wmic.exe -ArgumentList $WmicArgs;
```

But, why are you even using WMIC.exe?

There are easier ways to work with WMI, like using the PowerShell type accelerators [wmi], [wmiclass], [wmisearcher], and the Get-WmiObject cmdlet.

Comment: Im using WMIC because I need to find all of the locations where "administrator" is used.  I planned to get the output of wmic service and store that into a text file.  Then from here do a search on the word administrator and return that whole line to a new file if possible.

Comment: What information exactly do you need from WMI? What do you mean by "locations where Administrator is used?" I might be able to help you further.

Comment: I just needed to see what name and startname are running for the WMIC. Its a little vague cause im not sure how to explain what I am attempting to do.  I ended up going with a simple batch script to run the above command, pipe to a file and then parse that file for the keyword, and then finally send that information to a new file for later use.  Thank you for your help however.